# Getting endpoint in apache camel during runtime

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-camel

I am writing a generic route for http requests.and endpoint is not a static value.Code for route:

```
from("direct:processRequests")
                .split(body().method("getItems"), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
                .parallelProcessing()
                .to("direct:processRequest")
       .end();


         from("direct:processRequest")
         .when(body().method("getHttpDetails").method("getCallType").isEqualTo("GET"))
            .setProperty("type",body().method("getInterfaceId"))//to identity response later
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, body().method("getHttpDetails").method("getCallType"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, body().method("getHttpDetails").method("getPayLoadType"))
            .setHeader("Accept", body().method("getHttpDetails").method("getPayLoadType"))
            .to(body().method("getEndPointUri").toString())
```

Here i am trying to get endpoint from body.But as of now it fails with exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: ognl(simple{${body}}, getEndPointUri), please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:81)
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:211)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:107)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:113)
at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62)
at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:483)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createOutputsProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:446)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:413)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:165)
at org.apache.camel.model.ExpressionNode.createFilterProcessor(ExpressionNode.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.model.WhenDefinition.createProcessor(WhenDefinition.java:74)
at org.apache.camel.model.WhenDefinition.createProcessor(WhenDefinition.java:32)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:483)
at org.apache.camel.model.ChoiceDefinition.createProcessor(ChoiceDefinition.java:135)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:534)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:495)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:219)
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1069)
... 23 more
```

I know we can use toD() for dynamic endpoints.But for that we need some part of endpoint to be present in toD().Here i am trying to load entire endpoint dynamically.Is there any way around it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `configure` method in the `RouteBuilder` class is only invoked one time to setup the route, during start.

So if you want any dynamic uri, then use toD as the FAQ says
http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Thanks for responding.I am trying to get uri by (body().method("getEndPointUri").toString()).During start of camelContext it tries to resolves above expression,but it can be resolved only at runtime.Even with toD() its same issue.Is there anyway to set uri at rutime with any EIP's.

Comment: Use simple language which is built-in toD, eg: `toD("${body.getEndpointUri()}")` and since its a getter you can do that a bit shorter - `toD("${body.endpointUri}")`   - http://camel.apache.org/simple